# How to convert Date from serial number date MIXED with normal date in the same column

Tags: r, date

```
#A dataset call "charDate" , class is "character"
charDate
[1] "2017-01-19" "42431"      "42455"      "42430"  "2017-01-08"  "2017-01-08"
```

After applying  `as.Date` with  `origin ="1900-01-01` , its become `NA`

```
as.Date.character(charDate, origin = "1900-01-01")
[1] "2017-01-19" NA           NA           NA           "2017-01-08" "2017-01-08"
```

How to avoid it becoming `NA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in two steps.  First, convert the 'charDate' as in the OP's post and we get the NAs for the numeric elements.  Subset the elements from 'charDate' that corresponds to NA element in 'new' (`is.na`), convert it to `numeric` class and then do the `as.Date`

```
new <- as.Date(charDate, origin = "1900-01-01")
new[is.na(new)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(charDate[is.na(new)]), origin = "1900-01-01")
new
#[1] "2017-01-19" "2016-03-04" "2016-03-28" "2016-03-03" "2017-01-08" "2017-01-08"
```

#### data

```
charDate <-  c("2017-01-19", "42431",      "42455",      "42430", 
                                   "2017-01-08",  "2017-01-08" )
```

Comment: Perfect. Again , it is a excellent example to getting the usage of df[xx] <- somefunction(df[xx]) to deal with come multi step in one line. thankyou , again.